# Return duplicated rows by max column

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to get all rows duplicated (title) by max initID.

Here is my table :

```
  ID |      title      | revision | initID
  1  |    Mytitle 1    |    0     |  10
  2  |    Mytitle 1    |    1     |  10
  3  |    Mytitle 1    |    2     |  10
  4  |    Mytitle 1    |    0     |  20
  5  |    Mytitle 1    |    1     |  20

  6  |    Mytitle 2    |    0     |  30
  7  |    Mytitle 2    |    1     |  30

  8  |    Mytitle 3    |    0     |  40
  9  |    Mytitle 3    |    1     |  40
  10 |    Mytitle 3    |    0     |  50
  11 |    Mytitle 3    |    1     |  50
  12 |    Mytitle 3    |    2     |  50

  13 |    Mytitle 4    |    0     |  60
```

My goal is to check if there is multiple `initID` with the same title and get the duplicate lines with the MAX(initid).

For the example, I want to get this return from my request:

```
  4  |    Mytitle 1    |    0     |  20
  5  |    Mytitle 1    |    1     |  20
  10 |    Mytitle 3    |    0     |  50
  11 |    Mytitle 3    |    1     |  50
  12 |    Mytitle 3    |    2     |  50
```

If there is just one initID for a title I don't want to get the lines back.

Comment: Tag the DBMS that you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` with correlated subquery :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table t1 WHERE t.title = t1.title AND t1.initID <> t.initID) AND
      t.initID = (SELECT MAX(t1.initID) FROM table t1 WHERE t1.title  = t.title);
```

Answer (score 0):

use corelated subquery

```
 select t.* from table_name t
 where exists( select 1 from table_name t2 where t1.title=t2.title 
                   having count(*)>1)
 and t1.initID=( select max(initID) from table_name t2 where t1.title=t2.title)
```